# Why the region name not printing in Visual Studio 2010 when "hide collapsed region" is selected?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, printing

In Visual Studio 2008, when I print code with "hide collapsed region", the print result would include the region header name.

For example, if the code looks like this:

```
using ...
namespace Foo
{
   #region MyRegion1...

   #region MyRegion2...

   public void SomeAction{}

}
```

In Visual Studio 2008 print, it looks like:

```
using ...
namespace Foo
{
    MyRegion1

    MyRegion2

    public void SomeAction()
}
```

However, in Visual Studio 2010, it looks like:

```
using ...
namespace Foo
{




    public void SomeAction()
}
```

Notice that the region name is not printing, but it leaves an empty space. Is this a bug in VS 2010, or it is redesigned to hide the entire region with just a blank space. I can't find any option to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe also happens with my VS 2010 installation. I assume that this is by design (or perhaps by thoughtlessness, although that seems hardly believable, since they included this as a feature through an explicit checkbox option).

FYI, I tried changing this behavior through modifying the printer syntax highlighting settings, but to no avail.